# Window coordinates to camera angles?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

So I want to use quaternions and angles to control my camera using my mouse.

I accumulate the vertical/horizontal angles like this:

```
void Camera::RotateCamera(const float offsetHorizontalAngle, const float offsetVerticalAngle)
{
    mHorizontalAngle += offsetHorizontalAngle;
    mHorizontalAngle = std::fmod(mHorizontalAngle, 360.0f);

    mVerticalAngle += offsetVerticalAngle;
    mVerticalAngle = std::fmod(mVerticalAngle, 360.0f);
}
```

and compute my orientation like this:

```
Mat4 Camera::Orientation() const
{
    Quaternion rotation;
    rotation = glm::angleAxis(mVerticalAngle, Vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    rotation = rotation * glm::angleAxis(mHorizontalAngle, Vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

    return glm::toMat4(rotation);
}
```

and the forward vector, which I need for glm::lookAt, like this:

```
Vec3 Camera::Forward() const
{
    return Vec3(glm::inverse(Orientation()) * Vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
}
```

I think that should do the trick, but I do not know how in my example game to get actual angles? All I have is the current and previous mouse location in window coordinates.. how can I get proper angles from that?

**EDIT**: on a second thought.. my "RotateCamera()" cant be right; I am experiencing rubber-banding effect due to the angles reseting after reaching 360 deegres... so how do I accumulate angles properly? I can just sum them up endlessly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a cross section of the viewing frustum (the blue circle is your mouse position):

[image]

- Theta is half of your FOV
- p is your projection plane distance (don't worry - it will cancel out)

From simple ratios it is clear that:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But from simple trignometry

[image]

So ...

[image]

Just calculate the angle *psi* for each of your mouse positions and subtract to get the difference.

A similar formula can be found for the vertical angle:

[image]

Where A is your aspect ratio (width / height)

Comment: @MichaelIV stop it man, you're making me go red... No this is really just proving (in reverse) perspective projection - it helps for a graphics programmer to understand the math behind it all.

Comment: Exactly,not many people try to explain the stuff in SO in a detailed way :)